# Is it possible to return a javascript function via REST API with node/express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express

I have a unique use case where I would like to make a GET request to an endpoint and return a javascript function as the response. Im currently using node.js with express, but open to other frameworks.

So on the server side, if the client makes a request to get the function for "addition".

I want the server to send as the response a function that looks like so:

```
function add(num1, num2){
return num1 + num2
}
```

Which the the client can then take the response and utilize the function. eg:

```
axios(config).then(response=>{
myfunction = response
return myfunction(1,5)
//returns 6
})
```

Is there a way to 'serialize' the function on server side and convert it to an actual function on client side.

Comment: Yeah, with `new Function` or `eval`, but it's a somewhat weird thing to want to do

Comment: `return myfunction.toString();`

Comment: If it's a function you want to pass down, why don't you put the function on a module and then load it through `import()`?

Comment: does rpc work for you: Remote Procedure Call (RPC) is a protocol that one program can use to request a service from a program located in another computer on a network without having to understand the network's details. RPC is used to call other processes on the remote systems like a local system.

Comment: In short: don't. Rethink your architecture. Allow high level but very restricted expressions. But don't just return plain code.

Answer (score 1):

No matter what you do you will end up with a code you'll need to `eval` on client side, so you will always risk XSS and you need to make sure somehow that they don't contain dangerous code. From REST perspective this is not a big deal, you just need to return the javascript code with `application/javascript` MIME type and you can add it to the DOM with a SCRIPT tag or just use `eval` or `new Function`.

```
function add(a, b){
    return a+b;
}
```

From security perspective this can be even more problematic if your users can upload these functions fully or partially. If this is the case, then you need to convert the function code to a data format on the server and process it to make sure that it is safe to use in your clients. For example you can allow only operators like `+-*/` and you can allow accessing only local variables. The data format can be something like this:

```
{
    function: "add",
    params: ["a", "b"],
    code: [
        {
            "return": {"+": ["a", "b"]}
        }
    ]
}
```

Or you can use an already existing format, like the javascript AST. There are tools you can use for this format: https://github.com/search?l=JavaScript&q=ECMAScript+AST&type=Repositories

```
{
  "type": "Program",
  "start": 0,
  "end": 32,
  "body": [
    {
      "type": "FunctionDeclaration",
      "start": 0,
      "end": 32,
      "id": {
        "type": "Identifier",
        "start": 9,
        "end": 12,
        "name": "add"
      },
      "expression": false,
      "generator": false,
      "async": false,
      "params": [
        {
          "type": "Identifier",
          "start": 13,
          "end": 14,
          "name": "a"
        },
        {
          "type": "Identifier",
          "start": 15,
          "end": 16,
          "name": "b"
        }
      ],
      "body": {
        "type": "BlockStatement",
        "start": 17,
        "end": 32,
        "body": [
          {
            "type": "ReturnStatement",
            "start": 19,
            "end": 30,
            "argument": {
              "type": "BinaryExpression",
              "start": 26,
              "end": 29,
              "left": {
                "type": "Identifier",
                "start": 26,
                "end": 27,
                "name": "a"
              },
              "operator": "+",
              "right": {
                "type": "Identifier",
                "start": 28,
                "end": 29,
                "name": "b"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "sourceType": "module"
}
```

If you are afraid that your database contains unsafe functions or that it can be modified by attackers to distribute unsafe functions, then better to verify them again before you send them to the clients.

Comment: My use case is the client can only execute functions they themselves have written. I'm trying to accomplish something similar to a google cloud or aws lambda function for a specific use case.From what I have read if I want to proceed with this the javascript should be executed in a sandboxed environment like this JS interpreter, so I think that will be the route I go with. https://github.com/NeilFraser/JS-Interpreter

Comment: @corycorycory Yes, that is a possible solution too. Maybe even better as what I wrote, because you don't have to refuse unsafe code if it cannot exit the sandbox.